# jQuery ajax $.post refreshes page when called from validate plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

I can not figure out what is happening here but somehow my page is being refreshed/redirected when I call `$.post` inside of the `submitHandler` in the validate plugin.  The backend is just simply returning an HTTP status code of `200`.

Here is my code:

```
$('form[name=comment]').validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $('#postComment').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $.post('/blog/comments/create/', form.serialize(), function() {
            prependComment(form);
            return false;
        }).error(function() {
            alert('There was an issue when submitting this comment.');
        }).complete(function() {
            $('#postComment').removeAttribute('disabled'); 
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<form action="/blog/comments/create/" name="comment" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="1"/>
    <ul>
        <li>                    
            <input type="text" name="name" value="Your name" class="required"/>
        </li>
        <li>
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="55" class="required"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="submit" id='postComment' class="primary">Post comment</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: Side note - Nice avatar.

Comment: Have you tried `return false;` in your `submitHandler`?

Comment: I did.  I even set a breakpoint inside of the submitHandler. The moment $.post is called, it gets the page redirect to the action of the form.  Also, your avatar is equally appealing. :)

Comment: Which jQuery Validator are you using?

Comment: Since post is run asynchronously by default, the script will not stop to receive the error or success, it will continue to submit the form. Like Jared said have you tried return false ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the return false at the end of the submitHandler as well as inside of the success handler. I updated the post to reflect this.  This is the validation plugin I'm using: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: This part `form.serialize()` might need to be `$(form).serialize()`.

Comment: @intargc - See my last comment. Are you using a console like Firebug or Chrome Console? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Bingo!  I can't believe I didn't notice that!  Thanks Jared!  Care to make that a response so I can accept it?  :)

Comment: No problem, see my answer. Glad to help a fellow Beaker aficionado. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part `form.serialize()` should be `$(form).serialize()`. The `form` variable is a [DOM element, not a jQuery object](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions).